# Fluent Assertions compare string to Guid

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I am trying to find the most fluent manner to assert that a certain string is a valid Guid.

`iterTags.GUID` is a `string`.

My first attempt ended in error because `string`does not implement `Guid`. Okay, I saw it coming as it was a shot in the dark

```
iterTags.GUID.Should().BeAssignableTo<Guid>();
```

So i came up with this working solution but it's not fluent

```
Guid parsedGuid;
if (!Guid.TryParseExact(iterTags.GUID, "D", out parsedGuid))
    Assert.Fail("iterTags.GUID: '{0}' is not a valid guid");
```

Reading the [documentation](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/documentation) I found no better way of doing the assertion.

**My question:** Is there a **fluent** way of **asserting** a **string is** a valid **Guid**

Perhaps, something like...

```
iterTags.GUID.Should().BeParsedAs<Guid>()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Guid parsedGuid;
Guid.TryParseExact(iterTags.GUID, "D", out parsedGuid).Should.BeTrue("because {0} is a valid Guid string representation", iterTags.GUID);
```

or

```
new Action(() => new Guid(iterTags.GUID)).ShouldNotThrow("because {0} is a valid Guid string representation", iterTags.GUID);
```

Comment: Great solution. I just needed to explicitly create an Action:
new Action(() => new Guid(iterTags.GUID)).ShouldNotThrow("");

Comment: would you care to correct your second solution (or tell me i am wrong if it compiles in your VS)

Comment: sure. I do not have the Fluent Assertions installed, just got interested and read through the documentation :)

Comment: another option could be to write an extension -  but that would certainly require Fluent Assertions be referenced to test the code.

Comment: I do have it referenced so that would not be the problem. I should have seen the correct portion of the documentation but, honestly, did not understand it as i should - well paving the road for a better human :) thanks

Comment: Creating an extension is no big deal. It's just that, an extension method. The only thing FA adds is some plumbing to get some nice messages. See the extensibility section here https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki/Documentation#wiki-extensibility

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `not be empty` check on a GUID, that way you can use **FluentAssertions's** empty checking:

```
Guid.TryParse(iterTags.GUID, out var parsedIterTagsGUID)
parsedIterTagsGUID.Should().NotBeEmpty();
```

Or as extension:

```
    public static AndConstraint<FluentAssertions.Primitives.GuidAssertions> ShouldBeGuid(this object value, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
    {
        Guid.TryParse(value?.ToString(), out var guid);
        return guid.Should().NotBeEmpty(because, becauseArgs);
    }
```

The above can be done better, by extending something else like:

```
    public static AndConstraint<GuidAssertions> BeGuid(this StringAssertions value, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
    {
        Guid.TryParse(value.Subject, out var guid);
        return guid.Should().NotBeEmpty(because, becauseArgs);
    }

    public static AndConstraint<GuidAssertions> BeGuid(this ObjectAssertions value, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
    {
        return (value.Subject as Guid?).Should().NotBeNull().And.NotBeEmpty(because, becauseArgs);
    }
```

Or maybe even better by proposing a pull request on: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I ended up going with, inspired by [Nick N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869033/nick-n)'s answer.

The main difference is that the failure message is clearer about the string not being a GUID, where the `NotBeEmpty` condition would return a message saying that the input is empty.

```
public static class CustomAssertions
{
    public static AndConstraint<StringAssertions> BeGuid(this StringAssertions assertions, string because = "", params object[] becauseArgs)
    {
        var isGuid = Guid.TryParse(assertions.Subject, out _);

        Execute.Assertion
           .ForCondition(isGuid)
           .BecauseOf(because, becauseArgs)
           .FailWith("Expected a GUID converted to a string{reason}, but found {0}.", assertions.Subject);

        return new AndConstraint<StringAssertions>(assertions);
    }
}
```